# How to declare this nested array/list?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a custom class `Gene`

I want to declare an array or list (or something else whatever is better) named  `_slots` with 400 positions...something like `_slots[400]`.

Each `_slot` must contain a solution. A solution however is an array of my custom class `Gene` of 100.
something like this:

```
       _Slots
    -------------
0   | Gene[100] |
    --------------
1   | Gene[100] |
    --------------
2   | Gene[100] |
    --------------
3   | Gene[100] |
    --------------
4   | Gene[100] |
    --------------
...
400 | Gene[100] |
    --------------
```

What's the best way to declare this and have easy access to all members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *much* better way is to have a class that represents a `Slot`, which in turn manages 100 instances of `Gene`.

Then, have an array of 400 slots (or an `IEnumerable`, or a `List<Slot>`, whichever suits your needs).

```
public class Slot
{
    private Gene[] _genes;

    public Gene this[int index]
    {
        get{ return _genes[index];}
        set{ _genes[index] = value;}
    }

    public Slot(int count = 100)
    {
        _genes = new Gene[count];
    }
}    

IList<Slot> slotsList = Enumerable.Range(0,400)
                              .Select(i => new Slot())
                              .ToList();

//or an enumerable
IEnumerable<Slot> slots = slotsList;

//or an array 
Slot[] slotsArray = slotsList.ToArray();
```

Comment: perfect. what's the best type to use in a Genetic Algo? iEnumerable/List/array?

Comment: @Ray Depends on your requirements. Generally, you'd want to use the most abstract type possible. If all you need to do is iterate through `slots`, then use an `IEnumerable<T>`. If you want to iterate *and* swap slots, or assign a new `Slot` to a given index, then use an array. If you want to iterate, set new slots *and* shrink/grow the list of slots, then use a `List<T>`.

Comment: Minor update: if you use `Enumerable.Range().Select()`, don't forget to call `ToList`/`ToArray`.

Answer (score 1):

try use

```
List<Gene[]> MegaList = new List<Gene[]>();
MegaList.Add(new Gene[100]);
MegaList[0][0] = new Gene();
```

I strongly recommend wrap this functionality into class, it will allow you to extend it in future easily, 
f.e.:

```
public class MultiArray<T> : List<T> { }
...
MultiArray<Gene[]> Storage = new MultiArray<Gene[]>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the length of each dimension is the same, a 2-dimensional array seems logical.

```
Gene[,]
```

Alternatively, you can use a `List<Gene[]>` if the number of arrays is variable instead of a set value of 400

Answer (score 1):

```
   List<Gene>[] lst = new List<Gene>[400];
```